# Java CompareToIgnoreCase

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

im creating a method where a user input has to type A/B to get a return. how do i make my code case insensitive to make it work?

```
 String examcode (String code) {
    if (code.compareToIgnoreCase("A")) {
        EXAM_NAME = "Subject A";
    }
    else if (code.compareToIgnoreCase("B")) {
         EXAM_NAME = "Subject B";
    }
    else {
        EXAM_NAME = "no code";
    }
    return EXAM_NAME;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the method -
[`String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) which returns a `boolean` and does the job for what you are looking for.

`if (code.compareToIgnoreCase("A"))` is not valid since `compareToIgnoreCase` returns `int`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `equalsIgnoreCase()`, not `compareToIgnoreCase()`.

```
if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
   EXAM_NAME = "Subject A";
} //...
```

If you want to use `compareToIgnoreCase()` to check equality, you need to compare the result to `0`:

```
if (code.compareToIgnoreCase("A") == 0) {
    //...
```

just like any other `compareTo` method.  But there's no advantage to using it here.

### Edit:

An alternative to your entire approach might be to use a case-insensitive map instead.  Something like this:

```
Map<String, String> subjects = new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

subjects.put("A", "Subject A");
subjects.put("B", "Subject B");

//...
String subjectName = subjects.get(code);
if ( subjectName == null ) {
    subjectName = "no code";
}
```

Or, you could also use a normal case-sensitive map and just convert all keys to lower case before doing map operations.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the [javadoc for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) would have provided your answer for you.  Google would have turned that right up.

- Use `code.equalsIgnoreCase("your string")` which returns a boolean value, OR
- use `code.compareToIgnoreCase("your string") == 0`.  `compareToIgnoreCase` gives you a way to determine the "order" of two strings.  Again, enjoy the javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Use same code but equalsIgnoreCase(String) instead of compareToIgnoreCase(String).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `String#equalsIgnoreCase(String)` which returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

use String.toLowerCase() (or String.toUpperCase()) before comparing.

```
if (code.toLowerCase().equals("a")) {
    EXAM_NAME = "Subject A";
}
```

Note that like all string methods, code.toLowerCase does not change the string stored in 'code', but returns a copy of 'code's value all in lower case.